# For R Markdown, How do I display a matrix from R variable

Tags: r, matrix, latex, r-markdown

I have a rmd document where I have the following

````
```{r code_block, echo=FALSE}
A = matrix(c(1,3,0,1),2,2)
B = matrix(c(5,3,1,4),2,2)
```

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1  & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix} 
5 & 1 \\ 
3 & 4 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
````

Now I would like to instead of hard coding the LaTeX part manually, I could use the matrix from the variables A and B instead. How could this  be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for `knitr::knit_print()`.
You will find details about the `knitr::knit_print()` method in its dedicated vignette:

```
vignette('knit_print', package = 'knitr')
```

The goal is to provide a `knit_print` method for objects of class `matrix`. As other answers suggested, it could be useful to define operators.

You will find below an `Rmd` file that provides a solution to your problem. It also contains a proposal for operators.

The main feature of this answer is that you only have to write

```
`r A`
```

to output the matrix A in LaTeX inline mode (no `$` to type) and write

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
A
```
````

to write in LaTeX display mode.

I also propose you to define a `%times%` operator. Therefore, you only have to write:

```
`r A %times% B`
```

This answer is quite generic and you should be able to extend it to other objects.

````
---
title: "R Markdown: Display a Matrix for R Variable"
author: "Romain Lesur"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# Define a generic method that transforms an object x in a LaTeX string
as_latex = function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod('as_latex', x)
}

# Define a class latex for LaTeX expressions
as_latex.character = function(x) {
  structure(
    paste(x, collapse = ' '), 
    class = c('latex', 'character')
  )
}

# A character string of class latex is rendered in display mode
# Define a knit_print() method for the latex class
knit_print.latex = function(x, ...) {
  knitr::asis_output(
    paste0('$$', x, '$$')
  )
} 

# Now, define a method as_latex for matrix
as_latex.matrix = function(x, ...) {
  as_latex(c(
    '\\begin{bmatrix}',
    paste(
      t(x),
      rep(c(rep('&', nrow(x) - 1), '\\\\'), ncol(x)),
      collapse = ''
    ),
    '\\end{bmatrix}'
  ))
}

# Indicate to knitr that matrix are rendered as latex
knit_print.matrix = function(x, ...) {
  knitr::knit_print(as_latex(x))
}

# Build a knitr inline hook to display inline latex in inline mode
default_inline_hook = knitr::knit_hooks$get('inline')
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  x = paste(gsub('\\$\\$', '$', x))
  default_inline_hook(x)
})
```


```{r}
A = matrix(c(1,3,0,1),2,2)
B = matrix(c(5,3,1,4),2,2)
```


Now, matrix are rendered as LaTeX:

Matrix A in inline mode: `r A`

Matrix A in display mode:

```{r echo=FALSE}
A
```


### Operators

As other answers suggested, it could be useful to define operators.  
With the previous class, it is relatively straightforward:

```{r operators, include=FALSE}
`%times%` = function(x, y) {
  as_latex(sapply(list(x, '\\times', y), as_latex))  
}

`%add%` = function(x, y) {
  as_latex(sapply(list(x, '+', y), as_latex))  
}
```

Example in inline mode: `r A %add% A %times% B`

Display mode:
```{r echo=FALSE}
A %times% B
```
````

Comment: I really like this answer, but in a PDF rendering it threw an error about the $ placement. I was able to get it to work with a compromise: the end user needs to put in the $. To me this is ok, because it gives them the choice of `$inline$` vs. `$$display$$` rendering (the latter being centered on its own line). To make it work I made the `knit_print.latex()` function body simply be `knitr::asis_output(x)` and to use it add the `$` in the markdown like `Matrix A: $\`r A\`$` for inline and `$$\`r A %add% A %times% B\`$$` for display mode.

Comment: By the way, the implementation of `as_latex.matrix` is brilliant. Three of us gave three variations on that construction here but I find this one to be the most elegant.

Comment: @BrianStamper Glad you like this. For pdf_document support, I've slightly edited the `knit_print.matrix` method: now it works well for html and pdf document.

Comment: @BrianStamper Second update: I added a knitr hook to handle inline and display mode

Comment: Not only a solution but this is a model to learn from - I can see implementing other LaTeX object renderings in this manner now. Bounty awarded, many thanks.

Comment: if ncol diff from nrow, you will note that the matrix display is transposed, seems to work with       rep(c(rep('&', nrow(t(x)) - 1), '\\\\'), ncol(t(x))),

Answer (score 12):

Straightforwardly, you can write latex line. `writeLines()` or `cat()` would be helpful.

You can use `apply(A, 1)` with two step `paste()`.

1. `paste(collpase = "&")`: collapse each row
2. `paste(, "\\\\")`: collapse every column with `\\`

Then we can get the `latex` formula of matrix.

```
write_matex <- function(x) {
  begin <- "$$\\begin{bmatrix}"
  end <- "\\end{bmatrix}$$"
  X <-
    apply(x, 1, function(x) {
      paste(
        paste(x, collapse = "&"),
        "\\\\"
      )
    })
  writeLines(c(begin, X, end))
}
```

If you conduct this function, `write_matex(A)` gives

```
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0 \\
3&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
```

When you use chunk option `{r, results = 'asis'}`, you might see the matrix in both pdf and html.

[image]

---

### Latex block

Based on this function, you might freely use matrix in latex block. For this, `$$` should be removed in the function. Instead of `writeLines()`, `paste(collapse = "")` can be used.

```
write_matex2 <- function(x) {
  begin <- "\\begin{bmatrix}"
  end <- "\\end{bmatrix}"
  X <-
    apply(x, 1, function(x) {
      paste(
        paste(x, collapse = "&"),
        "\\\\"
      )
    })
  paste(c(begin, X, end), collapse = "")
}
```

In the text part, you can implement this function as

```
$$
`r write_matex2(A)` \times `r write_matex2(B)`
$$
```

In `r markdown`, this `r` with back quotation can attach your r function and variable. So you can get

[image]

As you can see, this is reproducible.

```
(C <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 2))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    3    5    7    9
#> [2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```

Similarly,

```
$$`r write_matex2(C)` + `r write_matex2(C)`$$
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I figured out a function that plugs the numbers from the matrix into the correct LaTeX code. In the code block where you use it you need `results='asis'` to get the LaTeX to render, and you can wrap the function in `writeLines` along with the other parts you need.

I'm still open to more elegant solutions.

````
```{r}
A <- matrix(c(1, 3, 0, 1), 2, 2)
B <- matrix(c(5, 3, 1, 4), 2, 2)

# Utility function to print matrices in proper LaTeX format
print_mat <- function(mat) {
  n <- nrow(mat)
  c('\\begin{bmatrix}',
    paste0(sapply(seq_len(n - 1),
                  function(i) paste0(mat[i, ], collapse = ' & ')),
           ' \\\\'),
    paste0(mat[n, ], collapse = ' & '),
    '\\end{bmatrix}')
} 

```

```{r, results = 'asis'}
writeLines(c('$$',
             print_mat(A),
             '\\times',
             print_mat(B),
             '$$'))
```
````

[image: Picture of resulting output]

Answer (score 1):

hello you can use `library(printr)` in a markdown block

```
knitr::kable(A ,  caption = "matrix A")
```

from
https://yihui.name/printr/

like this

````
```{r code_block, echo=FALSE}
A = matrix(c(1,3,0,1),2,2)
B = matrix(c(5,3,1,4),2,2)
knitr::kable(A ,  caption = "matrix A")
```
````

Comment: It only seems to print correctly if it is outside of the latex block ($$ $$)

Comment: It only works with: Some text `r kable(A)` * `r kable(B)` $$some latex code without matrix$$. If I do: $$some latex code `r kable(A)`$$, then the out put is "$$ Matrix A $$" there are extra $$ signs and the latex code before matrix A has disappeared.

Comment: While this answer outputs a nicely formatted table, it doesn't actually print the matrix in proper mathematical notation with the square brackets on left and right. I'm hoping someone can come up with the correct solution.