# Space matrix evenly using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am wondering how to put even white space around the elements in my matrix. I am not sure how to get this to render on stackoverflow, but the result has large spaces around the non-zero elements and I'd like spacing even. Another issue is the brackets don't contain the whole matrix, I'd like to sort that out too!

```
$$
\mathbf{G} = \left[\begin{array}

\alpha_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -r_{t-8} & \Delta tot_{t-4}  & \Delta mtpg_{t} & 0 & 0  \\
\beta_3 & \beta_1 & \beta_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \pi^e_t & \pi^{imp}_t  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\gamma_3\alpha_1 & 0 & 0 & \gamma_1 & \gamma_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & \gamma_3 & 0 & 0 & -\gamma_3r_{t-8} & \gamma_3\Delta tot_{t-4} & \gamma_3\Delta mtpg_{t} & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \delta & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\



\end{array}\right]
$$
```

Comment: Did you tag this correctly? This looks like LaTeX to me, not R.

Comment: I am looking for an answer to a Rmarkdown specific question. I've tried a host of LaTex solutions that don't work - so I am hoping someone with better knowledge of Rmarkdown (which I think uses LaTex) can help me.

Comment: A similar question with some useful answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591286/for-r-markdown-how-do-i-display-a-matrix-from-r-variable

Comment: Thanks @Brian Stamper, this is useful. However, I can't see how it answers my specific question. Maybe I've missed something?

Comment: Admittedly it does not get at your spacing issue, which indeed really is a general TeX question, as that is the underlying engine. You may want to try at https://tex.stackexchange.com/ (perhaps armed with a simpler example to demo the issue). The tricky part then is to get whatever solutions are offered there (usage of any special TeX packages, for example) incorporated into your Rmarkdown rendering process.